# Hexadecimal notation

Tags: hex, notation

I am reading a datasheet which uses the prefix `0x` (e.g. 0x2185AD12) to indicate the hexadecimal notation used. Suddenly, for this one diagram, they use a trailing `h` (e.g. 2185AD12h).

Is this just some inconsistency I can gloss over, or does the `h` suffix have a different meaning to the `0x` prefix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have the same meaning. Suffix `h` is more or less standard, and prefix `0x` comes specifically from C language.

Comment: `h` suffix is often used in electronics and in assembly languages